# What is the right function to use for for loop with 2 arguments?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm currently stuck and have no idea what function or code of line I should type. Hopefully, I can get some idea here. Whenever I try to print it keeps giving me an error.

```
for i1,i2 in range(len(mc_name, mc_class)):
    i1 = i1 + 1
    i2 = i2 + 1
    print(mc_name[i1] + mc_class[i2])
```

```
Error:
for i1,i2 in range(len(mc_name, mc_class)): 
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: In order for someone to help you get this code to do what you want, you'll have to give at least a hint of what that is.

Comment: Not totally clear, but I think you need two for loops, one for i1 and one for i2, with first for loop range(len(mc_name)), and the second for loop with range(len(mc_class)).

Base python len only accepts one argument, the length of the object or array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you might want `zip`.

```
for i1, i2 in zip(mc_name, mc_class):
    print(i1 + i2)
```

`zip` takes any number of iterables as arguments, and produces a single iterable that takes elements from each one -- hence it lets you iterate over two (or any number!) lists together in parallel.  If the input iterables are of unequal length, it stops as soon as any one of them is exhausted.

The equivalent using `len` would be to take the minimum length of the two lists as the argument to `range`:

```
for i in range(min(len(mc_name), len(mc_class))):
    print(mc_name[i] + mc_class[i])
```

but `zip` is preferred because it's more concise.

If you don't want to iterate over the two lists in parallel, and instead want the *product* of the two lists (i.e. every item with every other item) that would be a nested loop:

```
for i1 in mc_name:
    for i2 in mc_class:
        print(i1 + i2)
```

or `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
for i1, i2 in product(mc_name, mc_class):
    print(i1 + i2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably looking for the `zip()` function.

Assuming that, mc_name and mc_class have same length you can write as follows:

```
for (i1, i2) in zip(mc_name, mc_class):
    print(i1 + i2)
```

or, if you want to use `len` then write as follows

```
for i in range(len(mc_name)): # You can also use len(mc_class)
    print(mc_name[i] + mc_class[i])
```

Note : If you are using a for loop with `range` or `in` e.g.

```
for i in range(x):

or

for i in some_list:
```

You don't need to put this line `i+=1` or `i=i+1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
for i1,i2 in zip(mc_name, mc_class):
```